# Cannot cite using bibtex in blogdown?

Tags: r, blogdown, citations, bibliography

My question is similar to [How to cite using bibtex in blogdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46414520/how-to-cite-using-bibtex-in-blogdown/46488860#46488860)

However I have used Rmd file to cite but still not work. I don't know what's wrong and what I should add in the Rmd file.

I hope to cite Casella's Statistical Inference book in text and generate a reference.

For example

1. I created si.bib file from google scholar and put it into /content/post folder.
2. I created a Rmd file called "cite something" and included code like this

   ```
   ---
   title:  cite something
   author: ''
   date: '2018-05-17'
   slug: cite-something
   categories: []
   tags: []
   bibliography: [si.bib]
   link-citations: true
   ---
   @si
   # Reference
   ```

I hope to create something like this

[image]

But only get

[image]

My github repo is here: https://github.com/hc704/hc704.com

And my netlify website is here: hc704.netlify.com

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you are using `@si`, which seems to be wrong. `si` is the name of the file that contains all your references and it is not the key for Casella reference.

[Your current bib file](https://github.com/hc704/hc704.com/blob/2fcfda15028e3477b81d03ac39c3150ba70b759a/content/post/si.bib) is:

```
@book{casella2002statistical,
  title={Statistical inference},
  author={Casella, George and Berger, Roger L},
  volume={2},
  year={2002},
  publisher={Duxbury Pacific Grove, CA}
}
```

and then you should cite it as `@casella2002statistical` and not `@si` (which is the name of the file).

Comment: Get it! Thank you a lot Yihui!

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer Guilherme!